# WPF CheckBoxes in a ListBox: content bindings don't update properly (even though INotifyPropertyChanged has been implemented)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm trying to have a ListBox of CheckBoxes in WPF bound to an ObservableCollection of the INotifyPropertyChanged items.

I've tried all of the StackOverflow solutions I could find on this topic, but unfortunately none of those help. The usual INotifyPropertyChanged solution has been implemented, but the result is that there's no new CheckBox in the ListBox after the CreateRenameItemDialog dialog is finished.

Here's the code. First, the XAML ListBox code:

```xml
<ListBox Name="TodoListBox" BorderThickness="0" ItemsSource="{Binding TheTasks}">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <CheckBox Click="CheckBox_Click" Content="{Binding CheckBoxContent}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

The INotifyPropertyChanged implementation:

```cs
    public class CheckBoxContentNotifier : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _content;
        public string CheckBoxContent
        {
            get
            {
                return _content;
            }
            set
            {
                _content = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("CheckBoxContent");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

The MainWindow part:

```cs
        public ObservableCollection<CheckBoxContentNotifier> TheTasks { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            TheTasks = new ObservableCollection<CheckBoxContentNotifier>();
        }

        private void AddTaskButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var newTaskName = new CreateRenameItemDialog();
            newTaskName.Owner = this;
            if (newTaskName.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                TheTasks.Add(new CheckBoxContentNotifier { CheckBoxContent = newTaskName.NewTaskNameTextBox.Text });
            }
        }
```

I can clearly see in debug that the TheTasks collection is getting updated properly (there are all the new elements with proper content there), but the ListBox itself doesn't get updated visually, it's still empty. It seems that the bindings are not working.
Also, the PropertyChanged? event handler is null for some reason. This definitely is somehow related to the overall problem, but I just can't figure out what's wrong.
Any help would be deeply appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you set `DataContext` anywhere? Either from code behind or in your `XAML`.

Comment: @Sach Hello! Right now I do not. I'd tried to set DataContext of the ListBox with this ObservableCollection, and had also tried to set DataContext of an individual CheckBox to a CheckBoxContentNotifier, but none of those worked. It is possible I simply do not understand how I need to set DataContext, as I've never done this before.

Comment: Do `DataContext = this;` at the end of your `MainWindow()` constructor.

Comment: @Sach It works! I've spent the last 3 hours tracking this down... You're my savior today. Please do write the full answer, I'll gladly accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For binding to work you must set `DataContext` either from code behind (ideally, you should use a ViewModel), or from your `XAML`.

For code behind, simply in your constructor set it like so:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    TheTasks = new ObservableCollection<CheckBoxContentNotifier>();
    DataContext = this;
}
```

Do read up about data binding, and possible use of `MVVM` architecture and using a `ViewModel`. That's when you can realize the full potential of `WPF`.

Comment: I'm so grateful for this! Thank you again! I know about MVC in general and have of course used Models/Views/Controllers in other GUI development frameworks (I'm coming from the C++/Qt background), but I do need to read up about how it works in WPF in particular, because I did not understand DataContext before this. This is a small WPF app to educate myself on the basics, but in bigger projects I'll most certainly have to use MVVM fully.